# How to display graphics in javafx ListView

Tags: listview, graphics, javafx, icons

I have two TreeViews of dir structures and their files and I want to show an indication of the status of the files(whether the file is unchanged, new, changed, deleted) somewhere in the same window. List views come to mind, and they seem to be capable of working with images somehow, but I don't know how to use them exactly, or whether they are indeed the best way to implement this.

So how do I achieve something like in the picture?(For illustration only, disregard the actual placement and color of the dots.)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add a new `TreeItem`, you can pass alot things to the constructors parameter of `TreeItem`. So if you pass FX containers like `HBox` it gets simply displayed like the following:

```
    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    Label label = new Label("file");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView("path to image");
    hbox.getChildren().add(label);
    hbox.getChildren().add(imageView);
    TreeItem itm = new TreeItem(hbox);
    rootItem.getChildren().add(itm);
```

i hope this helps.